# NGINX Redirect while avoiding perpetual loops

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to create an nginx config that routes all traffic sent to a server on port 80 to port 5000 instead except for the following scenarios:

If the address is /Home/Error I want it to be redirected instead to https://somesite.azurewebsites.net/home/unblock

If the address is /Home/BlockerHasError I want it to be redirected instead to https://somesite.azurewebsites.net/home/error

If the address is /Home/ErrorNotBlocked I want it to be redirected instead to https://somesite.azurewebsites.net/home/notblocked

If the address is /Home/Foo I want it to be redirected instead to /Home/Error but I don't want the earlier rule to come into play. Basically if someone goes to /Home/Error it should be redirected to
https://somesite.azurewebsites.net/home/unblock, but if they go to /Home/Foo they should go to /Home/Error (the actual page, not with a redirect).

I need the redirects to be 302's and be case insensitive.

I've come close with the following configuration but I can't seem to get the /Home/Foo redirects to work. No redirect is happening, I'm just left at http://mysite/Home/Foo instead of http://mysite/Home/Error.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name myServerName;

    location /Home/Error {
        return 302 https://somesite.azurewebsites.net/home/unblock;
    }

    location /Home/BlockerHasError {
        return 302 https://somesite.azurewebsites.net/home/error;
    }

    location /Home/ErrorNotBlocked {
        return 302 https://somesite.azurewebsites.net/home/notblocked;
    }

    location /Home/Foo {
        return 302 /Home/Error;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;    
    }
}
```

Comment: Your requirements are contradictory - it's not possible to satisfy both requirement 2 and requirement 4 at the same time. You will have to redirect to `/Home/RealErrorFoo` in your requirement 4.